# How to add scrollbar to fullcalendar schedular in resource

Tags: html, fullcalendar, scrollbar, fullcalendar-scheduler

In my case I have multiple technician and I am showing technician in resorce view in fullcalendr schedular.
If there are many technician then resource column are adjusted in same width but I have not given the width. I want if mltiple technician then scroll bar should be there in full calendar.
Now it is showing like this I want scroll bar here

[image]

I have used the full calendar schedular plugin.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@6.1.8/index.global.min.js

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of this issue please with relevant code? As standard, it should  scroll - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvREjGx